# Filter functionalty is not working as per expected using Angular.js.and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have an issue. I need to filter data from table using `restaurant name` using Angular.js. I have an search box. if user is typing the first letter of the name,all names related to that letter should filtered. Its not happening like that.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:10px; width:300px;">
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Type Restaurant Name" name="q" type="text" ng-model="searchProduct.rest_name">
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sl. No</th>
<th>Restaurant Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
   <tr dir-paginate="cus in ($parent.labelResults=(listOfCustomerData  | filter:searchProduct.rest_name:startsWith | orderBy:'rest_name')) | itemsPerPage:5 track by $index" current-page="currentPage">
  <td>{{itemsPerPage *(currentPage-1)+$index+1}}</td>
   <td>{{cus.rest_name}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My controller side code is given below.

```
$http({
        method:'GET',
        url:"php/customerInfo.php?action=disp",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        console.log('res',response.data);
        $scope.listOfCustomerData=response.data;
    },function errorCallback(response) {
    })

$scope.startsWith = function (actual, expected) {
    var lowerStr = (actual + "").toLowerCase();
    return lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0;
  }
```

Here suppose i have many restaurant name such as Anjum,A&P Chinese Food Express,Bookers BBQ & Crab Shack,Butcher And The Baker,    Cactus Club Stephen Avenue,Cactus Club - Macleod Trail. Here when user is typing only a inside the search box the names started with a should filter but its not happening like that. If i am assigning the static value to the object `$scope.listOfCustomerData` this functionality is working as per expected but i am dynamically fetching the data using PHP.but in my case its not happening like that. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this -

`<input class="form-control" placeholder="Type Restaurant Name" name="q" type="text" ng-model="searchProduct">
</div>`

`<tr dir-paginate="cus in listOfCustomerData  | filter:searchProduct | orderBy:'rest_name' | itemsPerPage:5 track by $index" current-page="currentPage">`

In your controller define - `$scope.searchProduct = '';`

Comment: By doing as per you its throwing this `angularjs.js:107 Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$parse/syntax?p0=%7C&p1=not%20a%20primary…expression&p2=77&p3=(%24parent.labelResults%3D(listOfCustomerData%20%20%7CNaNilter%3AstartsWith%3A'rest_name'%3A%20%7C%orderBy%3A'rest_name'))&p4=%7C%orderBy%3A'rest_name'))` error.

Comment: But if iam assigning the static data to that `$scope.listOfCustomerData ` object my code is also working but i am retrieving data from DB. so its not working as per exepected.

Comment: Why are you using $parent.labelResults ?

Comment: i am using this to fetch all filtered data from table after one button click.Here i have not mentioned that button.

Comment: refer to the edited answer. If it is working for you. You don't need to press any button it will automatically filter the results.

Comment: Can you add fiddle for what you are trying?

Comment: How can i add the database part in fiddle.?I have already told its working while i am taking the static data but not like above post.

Comment: I think you are calling API on every search. But dir-paginate is UI side filter thats why it is working for static data and not for dynamic one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116694/discussion-between-subhra-and-neha-soni).